# PHP router with switch statement and regular expressions not working

Tags: php, regex, switch-statement, router

I have this code in php:

```
$route = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);

        switch ($route) {
            case '':
                echo "root";
                break;
            case '/':
                echo "root";
                break;
            case (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$/", $route) ? true : false):
                echo "db";
                break;
            default:
                header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
                http_response_code(404);
                print(http_response_code());
                break;
        }
```

The regexp has to match all routes containing alphanumeric characters and - and _. But it doesn't, instead all *slips* to the default option, 404.

Probably it is something wrong with the pregmatch inside the switch.
Please help.

Comment: `switch`doesn't particularly work for your case. Use `if..else`.

Comment: Have you tested it anyhow? Maybe you get `/route_name` instead of `route_name`?

Comment: Also your route should be `true` or `false` to match, so will never work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few issues:

1. `REQUEST_URI` will return string with leading `/`, so you must add it in your regex: `/^\/[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$/`
2. `switch` checks if `case` value matches with provided value, so you should compare it with `true` instead of `$route`:

```php
switch (true) {
    case $route == '':
        ...
    case $route == '/':
        ...
    case preg_match("/^\/[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$/", $route):
        ...
}
```

But in that case it's better to use simple if conditions:

```php
if (empty($route) || $route == '/') {
    echo 'root';
    return; // Use early return in order not to jump to other cases
}

if (preg_match("/^\/[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$/", $route)) {
    echo 'db';
    return;
}


header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
http_response_code(404);
print(http_response_code());
```